# Clustering symmetric distance matrix

Tags: clustering, algorithms, matrix, spectral-analysis

Below is a symmetric matrix $A$ with distances between observation $i$ and $j$.

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 9  & 8 & 6 & 3\\
9 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 8\\
8 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 9\\
6 & 7 & 6 & 0 & 7\\
3 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 0\\
\end{matrix}
$$

My goal is to assign these into separate groups/clusters such the distance between observations within the group is minimized.

For example, the distance between observation 2 and 3 is 1 ($A_{23}$)

The distance between observation 1 and 5 is 3 ($A_{15}$)

According to that, observation 2 and 3 are likely to be part of the same "cluster". 1 and 5 also have a small distance of 3 between them, which also mean they should be part of the same "cluster". As you can see, observation 4 is very far from any other observation, which means it should be assigned to another "cluster".

The types of groups I initially trying to achieve according to the above example is as follows:

```
Cluster 1: observations 1, 5
Cluster 2: observations 2, 3
Cluster 3: observation 4
```

Do you know of an algorithm that can answer this kind of a problem?

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701/readings/Luxburg06_TR.pdf

Comment: **This is not a distance matrix!**  The zeros at positions (2,5) and (5,2) indicate that the corresponding objects are co-located.  Therefore they must exhibit identical distances to all other objects: this would be manifested as *identical* columns 2 and 5 and identical rows 2 and 5, but that's far from the case.  Any attempt at clustering that assumes these are distances would therefore be invalid, in the off chance it actually succeeded.

Comment: @whuber indeed you're right, I did not think of that when I created this example. It is meant to be a distance matrix - I will change the distances to remove the co-located points at (2,5).

Comment: @whuber Also as far as that's relevant distance here is more conceptual. i.e. "distance between observations" not distance in the sense of kilometers on a 2d plane.

Comment: It's not valid to call it a distance unless it satisfies the triangle inequality.  My previous comment provides a simple demonstration that your matrix violates the triangle inequality.  Many clustering methods assume the triangle inequality is satisfied, so it's important to be clear concerning whether your actual problem concerns a true distance matrix or not.

Comment: @whuber, please check the updated matrix with correct numbers for the distances, which now satisfies the triangle inequality. Is there an approach you know about that I can use in order to achieve the above mentioned goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hierarchical clustering.

This gives you the best control over how distances of *groups* are computed. Because there is more than one way of linking.

Comment: Hey Anony-Mousse, thank you for your suggestion, I'm currently looking at the documentation of it. May I ask to see an example of how this can be used with symmetric distance matrix? Thanks

Comment: You call agnes(X)

Comment: The mentioned function is in R, right? I'm working on a project in Python, do you know what is the equivalent function in Python maybe? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that also exist in scipy and takes about 10 second to find.